# Creating SEF urls using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

How can I change a url of the following format

```
  example.com/page/1
```

To

```
example.com/index.php?page=1
```

?

When I enter

```
example.com/page/1
```

it should  redirect to

```
  example.com/index.php?page=1
```

What changes do I need to do in my .htaccess file?

**folder structure is as follows**

```
   -Public_html
      .htaccess
       index.php
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in your `public_html/.htaccess` file

```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^page/([0-9])/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

`RewriteCond` checks if the requested filename  or directory already exist, `RewriteRule` will be skipped.

Answer (score 2):

You can put this code in your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

With only this code, you can now access `http://example.com/page/55` and see the content of `/index.php?page=55` for instance.

**But**... the thing is, you're still able to access `http://example.com/index.php?page=55` and it creates a duplicate content: very bad for referencing (Google, and others).

More info about duplicate content: [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en).

**Solution**: you can add another rule to redirect `http://example.com/index.php?page=55` to `http://example.com/page/55` (**without any infinite loop**)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php\?page=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ page/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

Note 1: make sure (in Apache configuration file) that you've enabled *mod_rewrite* and allowed *htaccess* files.

Note 2: since your rule creates a *virtual* directory (`/page/`) you'll have some problem if you're using *relative* paths for your html resources. Make sure all your links (js, css, images, href, etc) begins with a leading slash (`/`) or instead, add a base right after `<head>` html tag: `<base href="/">`

Answer (score 2):

in my answer I assume you are using linux,
I also assume you will have more complicated cases such as more than
one parameters you will want to catch

example.com/page/1/3
in this case I think you will have to use parsing the url in your index.php

first you will have to setup the .htaccess file in your site root, also you will have to make sure mod_rewrite is enabled in your apache configuration

in case you are running debian you can run this command in terminal
to make sure this mod is enabled:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

add htaccess file to the root of where your index php file is located example:

/var/www/html/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
</IfModule>
```

according to my solution in your index.php you must have function that can parse the url request

```
/*
$base path is used only if you running your site under folder
example.com/mysitefolde/index.php
*/
function getUrlParams($basePath = ''){
  $request  = str_replace($basePath, "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  return  explode('/', $request);
}
```

index.php request to example.com/page/1/2

```
$request = getUrlParams($rootPath);
$module = $request[0]; // page
$moduleValue = $request[1]; // 1
$moduleValue2 = $request[2]; // 2
```

Comment: Thinking about a routing system is fine. Instead of your specific code, i would have developed a router class with MVC pattern to be more generic/reusable. But i really doubt, looking at the question, that OP needs a complex system as this one. And, by the way, your solution does not settle the duplicate content problem at all

Comment: duplicate content problem ?

Comment: no it depends what you are doing in your index.php if you are loading the same page it is your problem but base on my solution you suppose to do something with the url values such as loading different content.

Comment: Yeah my mistake, considering that you're not catching `page` get parameter to serve content